# Can I drop the /g/ sound in the pronunciation of longer?

Tags: pronunciation

I know some words like '' finger'' and ''stronger'' have /ŋg/pronunciation, and the rule of pronouncing
/ŋg/ may vary. According to Merriam-Webster (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/long) you could say /ˈlȯŋ-​gər/  also  /-​ər/. But on Cambridge dictionary site, it is said that the pronunciation of younger, younger and stronger has /ŋg/ sound.
Which pronunciation is more commonly used, or both are accepted?

Comment: You're going to need to say which version of English you're using because the answer will vary.

Comment: I'd say as long as the version used by native English speakers. You said the answer will vary, this means both /ˈlȯŋ-​gər/ and /ˈlȯŋ ər/ are accepted?

Comment: @Laurel: Thank you! I've read that thread but still find it a bit unclear as I'd really want to know if  /ˈlȯŋ-​gər/ and /ˈlȯŋ ər/ are both accepted (equally)?

Comment: A duplicate of the question linked by Laurel, which is itself a duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288116/strong-str%c9%94%cb%90%c5%8b-%e2%86%92-stronger-str%c9%94%cb%90%c5%8b%c9%a1%c9%99r-why-do-we-have-to-put-an-extra-g-in-f).

Comment: @KillingTime I do not believe that this aspect varies by "which version of English" you use.  The difference between *singer* and *finger* is universal to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when the *-ng-* is in the middle of a morpheme, it is pronounced /-ŋg-/ as in *finger, anger, English, hunger* etc. Comparatives and superlatives are also pronounced with /-ŋg-/ (e.g. *longer, younger, stronger*). Other words such as *sing-er, hang-er, ring-er* are pronounced with /-ŋ-/ only (but in some dialects, they're pronounced with /-ŋg-/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'd like to ask if the version '' /ˈlȯŋ ər/ is also accepted somehow?

Comment: @Lala - /ˈlȯŋ ər/  for the adjective "longer"? No. /ˈlȯŋ ər/ is a noun which means a person who longs. So no, it's not acceptable for the adjective.

Comment: Thank you @BrLn!! I asked this question because on Merriam Webster, it is said that the pronunciation of longer is ''longer\ ˈlȯŋ-​gər  also  -​ər \'', but on Cambridge dictionary site, there is only one option for the pronunciation of longer which is '' / lȯŋ-​gər/'', so I find it a bit confusing.

Comment: Depends. There are two _-er_ suffixes in English. The agentive 'one who Vs' as in _longer_ 'one who longs', which doesn't use /ɡ/, and the comparative 'more', as in _longer_ 'more long', which does use /ɡ/. This is a fact about these suffixes and the final /ŋɡ/ cluster. It doesn't generalize to final /mb/ clusters, for instance.